# My HP laptop is getting heated up rapidly when in battery

Tags: windows-7, laptop

Recently I have noticed a very interesting thing . I am using a HP G4 laptop with windows 7 , when in charge the laptop is performing well when unplugged it is showing a sudden rise in CPU and getting heated up badly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for this problem , this is due to the power options default settings .This problem is seen for the HP G42 series laptops with windows 7 . For this combination ,the system cooling policy in the advanced power settings on battery will be passive which is the cause for the problem . So when you are using the laptop in battery , the fan will be off which will make your processor to heat up  and the CPU consumption will be near to 100 % .